# Symbol(s) not found. Collect2: Id returned 1 exit status

Tags: objective-c, linker, compiler-errors

I received the following error:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SurveyDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-SurveyDelegate in Menus.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The error was caused by removing SurveyDelegate and was fixed when I removed the code that tried to use a survery delegate. Why isn't it giving normal compile error? I already tried cleaning the project? In fact, it also let me declare a `SurveyDelegate` elsewhere and this error wasn't giving either a linker or compiler error.

**Other questions**

[Objective c id returned 1 exit status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601092/objective-c-id-returned-1-exit-status) - same name, but different problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove files of SurveyDelegate from project. Check the project directory in Finder for SurveyDelegate files. Remove them and recreate in XCode if necessary. Don't forget about cleaning (Cmd + Shift + K).

Comment: It's a couple of months after this post. I had the exact same problem and by following your steps solved the issue. Is there an explanation for this? It seems so... random!? Thank you so much both @Casebash and @NR4TR

Comment: The connection between the project and the file has been broken and we should perform these actions to reduce possible mismatches between the file and the project.