# Undefined symbol error from ld using Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I Got such error...

I don't know what does it mean...

`Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CoffeeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-CoffeeViewController in RootViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Can anyone tell me what to do?

this is the code

in .h
i have done this

`#import < UIKit/UIKit.h>`
`#import "CoffeeViewController.h"`

`@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController`    {
    `CoffeeViewController *coffeeView;

}`

`@property(nonatomic, retain) CoffeeViewController *coffeeView;

@end`

in .m
i have done this

```
 if(self.coffeeView==nil){
CoffeeViewController *viewController = [[CoffeeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CoffeeViewController" bundle:nil];
self.coffeeView = viewController;
[viewController release];
}
```

When I execute this code ...

it is giving me an error...

Comment: Has this class been added to your target?

Comment: put some code here. and tell us on which action you got this error..

Comment: @nick and @Rakesh...I have posted the code

Comment: How to check my class has been added into target or not?? sorry a newbie here :(

Comment: In XCode 4 open the rightbar when editing the CoffeeViewController.m file and check if the target in the target list is cheked.

Comment: In Xcode3 you have the left side bar with the folder. A lil bit down there is the Targets folder, look if the file is in the compile sources folder.

Comment: Just a tip, because your a newbie. It's obvious that you need a solution to an error, that's why your asking a question here. Give us a clue about the problem in the title. You may as well have written "I need an answer".

Comment: @daniel ..right :) I'll do that next time..sorry..:)/..@nick...That was the answer..done thanks buddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the protocol:

In Xcode3 you have the left side bar with the folder. A lil bit down there is the Targets folder, look if the file is in the compile sources folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
[Symbol(s) not found. Collect2: Id returned 1 exit status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819408/symbols-not-found-collect2-id-returned-1-exit-status)

Answer (score 0):

See any of Your Frameworks are missing or deleted!!